# Problem with sorting literature order by entry type (misc, book,...) in BiBTeX

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, sorting

EDIT: I edited a "main" file and I added a `.bib` file.

I have problem with BibTeX - concretely with sorting literature order by entry type. The `.cls` file is [HERE](http://exdb.fit.cvut.cz/browser/zp/1213-zima/martiada/FITthesis.cls?rev=1217) and `.bst` file is [HERE](https://github.com/JeanVEGA/MI-MPR-DIP/blob/master/csn690.bst).

Error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.402 \newlength{\bibhang}

?
```

Document:

```
\documentclass[thesis=B,czech]{FITthesis}[2012/06/26]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}


\department{text}
\title{text}
\authorGN{text}
\authorFN{text}
\authorWithDegrees{text}
\supervisor{text}
\acknowledgements{text}
\abstractCS{text}
\abstractEN{text}
\placeForDeclarationOfAuthenticity{text}
\declarationOfAuthenticityOption{1}
\keywordsCS{text}
\keywordsEN{text}

\begin{document}

\begin{introduction}
    %
\end{introduction}

\chapter First

    \cite{alfa}
    \cite{beta}
    \cite{gama}
    \cite{delta}

\begin{conclusion}
    %
\end{conclusion}

\bibliographystyle{csn690}
\bibliography{mybibliographyfile}

\appendix

\end{document}
```

`.bib` file:

```
@BOOK{gama,
 author = {Gama},
 title = {1.},
 subtitle = {Gama},
 address = {Gama},
 publisher = {Gama},
 year = {Gama},
}

@MISC{delta,
  Author = {2.},
  Institution = {Delta},
  note = {Delta},
  Year = {2000},
  Title = {Delta}
}

@MASTERTHESIS{beta,
  author = {Beta},
  title = {3.},
  year = {2000},
  school = {Beta},
  type = {Beta},
  url = {http://www.beta.com},
}

@MANUAL{alfa,
    title = "4.",
    url = "http://www.alfa.com",
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I edited a "main" file and I added a `.bib` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the error with macro `\bibhang` comment the call of `biblatex` (both `natbib` and `biblatex` defines a macro `\bibhang`):

```
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
```

To use package `biblatex` you have to change some lines in your MWE:

- change `\bibliography{mybibliographyfile}` to `\printbibliography`
- add after calling package `biblatex` the macro `\addbibresource{mybibliographyfile.bib}`
- comment `%\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}`
- To use BibTeX with `biblatex` add the `biblatex` option `,backend=bibtex`
- Do not use bibliographystyle `csn690` with BibLaTeX.

Because you don't specified which error you have with the sorting I can't help you there. I suugest you can ask a follow up question for this.

So this should compile:

```
\documentclass[thesis=B,czech]{FITthesis}[2012/06/26]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{dirtree}
%\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[%
  defernumbers=true
 ,natbib
 ,backend=bibtex
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybibliographyfile.bib}

\department{text}
\title{text}
\authorGN{text}
\authorFN{text}
\authorWithDegrees{text}
\supervisor{text}
\acknowledgements{text}
\abstractCS{text}
\abstractEN{text}
\placeForDeclarationOfAuthenticity{text}
\declarationOfAuthenticityOption{1}
\keywordsCS{text}
\keywordsEN{text}

\begin{document}

\begin{introduction}
    %
\end{introduction}

\chapter First

    \cite{alfa}
    \cite{beta}
    \cite{gama}
    \cite{delta}

\begin{conclusion}
    %
\end{conclusion}

%\bibliographystyle{csn690}
\printbibliography

\appendix

\end{document}
```

Comment: This produces error:

! Package biblatex Error: File 'Sablona_BP_UTF-8.bbl' not created by biblatex.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.29 \begin{document}
                     ^^M
?

Comment: It has been successfully compiled but I need to sort it order by entry type. For example I would like to have a type BOOK in the first place. And I really need to use `csn.bst` because of my mother tongue.